# Create array of words from a string of text

Tags: php, split, cpu-word

I would like to split a text into single words using PHP. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

My approach:

```
function tokenizer($text) {
    $text = trim(strtolower($text));
    $punctuation = '/[^a-z0-9äöüß-]/';
    $result = preg_split($punctuation, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        $result[$i] = trim($result[$i]);
    }
    return $result; // contains the single words
}
$text = 'This is an example text, it contains commas and full-stops. Exclamation marks, too! Question marks? All punctuation marks you know.';
print_r(tokenizer($text));
```

Is this a good approach? Do you have any idea for improvement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the class \p{P} which matches any unicode punctuation character, combined with the \s whitespace class.

```
$result = preg_split('/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This will split on a group of one or more whitespace characters, but also suck in any surrounding punctuation characters. It also matches punctuation characters at the beginning or end of the string. This discriminates cases such as "don't" and "he said 'ouch!'"

Comment: +1, not sure, tho, how this will deal with äöüß. Does regex normally classify äöüß as word characters?

Comment: Thank you. This would't probably work for English texts but I also want to extract German umlauts (ä, ö, ü), the "ß" and numbers in a string. The "\W" wouldn't extract "Fri3nd", would it?

Comment: Seems it does not, but updated answer with something similar that works.

Comment: Updated answer works with perl (which php regex are based on): $ echo "äöüß, test" | perl -e 'while (<>) { if (/([\p{P}\s]+)/) { print "$1\n"; } }'
,

Comment: Should one split don't into don and t?

Comment: Updated it to handle such a case :)

Comment: Thanks, marcog, it works perfectly!
But is it really better than my updated code above? Actually, what is the difference between our approaches? Is one faster than the other one?

Comment: In your approach you're specifying the non-punctuation characters. You will be therefore be missing some cases, e.g. á. Why try manually specify them when the whole set of unicode punctuation characters has already been defined? And like eed3si9n pointed out with my original answer, yours will break up words such as don't.

Comment: @marcog Any idea what would be the Javascript equivalent of this? I tried doing `str.split(/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/);` but it doesn't work. Please help..

Comment: What to do if i want to remove all numbers?

Answer (score 14):

Tokenize - [strtok](https://www.php.net/strtok).

```
<?php
$text = 'This is an example text, it contains commas and full stops. Exclamation marks, too! Question marks? All punctuation marks you know.';
$delim = ' \n\t,.!?:;';

$tok = strtok($text, $delim);

while ($tok !== false) {
    echo "Word=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok($delim);
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't work if you get a : or ; or any other punctuation character you haven't accounted for.

Comment: @marcog, I added : and ;. Doesn't {P} catch apostrophe and hyphen?

Comment: What about cases such quoting? My updated answer discriminates between these cases.

Comment: Excellent idea. Added +1. The only thing is that there should be double quotes around $delim = " \n\t,.!?:;"; With the single quotes it does not work correctly, it splits by the letter n too.

Answer (score 3):

I would first make the string to lower-case before splitting it up. That would make the `i` modifier and the array processing afterwards unnecessary. Additionally I would use the `\W` shorthand for non-word characters and add a `+` multiplier.

```
$text = 'This is an example text, it contains commas and full stops. Exclamation marks, too! Question marks? All punctuation marks you know.';
$result = preg_split('/\W+/', strtolower($text), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

---

**Edit**   Use the [Unicode character properties](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.unicode) instead of `\W` [as marcog suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790596/split-a-text-into-single-words/790602#790602). Something like `[\p{P}\p{Z}]` (punctuation and separator characters) would cover the characters more specific than `\W`.

Comment: Thanks, the idea to perform strtolower() before is very good. I'll use this.

Comment: What purpose does `strtolower()` serve if you are splitting with `\W`?  Do you want to add a `u` pattern modifier?  A note to researchers... `\W` will not match an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
str_word_count($text, 1);
```

Or if you need unicode support:

```
function str_word_count_Helper($string, $format = 0, $search = null)
{
    $result = array();
    $matches = array();

    if (preg_match_all('~[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}' . preg_quote($search, '~') . ']+~u', $string, $matches) > 0)
    {
        $result = $matches[0];
    }

    if ($format == 0)
    {
        return count($result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn't work. "Fri3nd" wouldn't be extracted but it should.

Comment: I don't understand why "Fri3nd" should be extracted. Removed from the array, broken down into "Fri3" and "nd" (or similar)? O.o

Comment: If you want to consider numbers as words just do str_word_count_Helper($string, 1, '0123456789');

Comment: [Native PHP functions that allow double-dot range syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72865139/2943403) demonstrates that `str_word_count($string, 1, '0..9')` will do.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use PHP strtok() function to fetch string tokens from your large string. you can use it like this:

```
 $result = array();
 // your original string
 $text = 'This is an example text, it contains commas and full stops. Exclamation marks, too! Question marks? All punctuation marks you know.';
 // you pass strtok() your string, and a delimiter to specify how tokens are separated. words are seperated by a space.
 $word = strtok($text,' ');
 while ( $word !== false ) {
     $result[] = $word;
     $word = strtok(' ');
 }
```

see more on php documentation for [strtok()](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Comment: what is the difference between this and explode(' ', $text);

Comment: The code sample in the question is a tokenizer, my answer was implying that PHP has a string tokenizer built-in. Also explode() will return all of the words of the text at once, but using strtok() the caller has the choice to stop searching for words in the text, as soon as a desired condition is met. Other than this, I can't think of any other difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the method explode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$words = explode(" ", $sentence);
```

Comment: not works with 2 or more consecutive spaces. you have to use a foreach with `explode(" ", $sentence)` within `if($word == "") continue;` so you could avoid empty words.