# error in splitting a sentence into words, split() is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated

i am trying to parse the sentence and split it into words

> $allwords=split(" ",$mybigsentence);

i am getting this error in the above line

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projecte\src\admin\botloaderfuncs.php

what is going wrong in it.
using php 5.0.3

Comment: use explode inplace of split, split is deprecated (eg it will be removed from php in a future version)

Comment: -1.  Could have easily googled "php split deprecated."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

From: https://www.php.net/split

DEPRECATED means it will be removed soon in future PHP versions.

Take a look at this solution: [Split text into words and consider numbers with decimals as a whole "word"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600649/split-text-into-words-problem-php-complicated-problem)

Should definitely give the code you need, the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

`split` is designated for splitting by a regular expression. In your case, you're splitting the string by a substring, so [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) will work for you (and using it is more efficient as well).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `explode` for your problem. It will work ;)