# PHP split UTF8 text into words and punctuation

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-split

I need utf-8 text like this:

> "Bára, ta která má hezké oči. To je, ale nepříčetně nehorázné!"

split into array of words and punctuation, like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Bára
    [1] => ,
    [2] => ta
    [3] => která
    [4] => má
    [5] => hezké
    [6] => oči
    [7] => .
    [8] => To
    [9] => je
    [10] => ,
    [11] => ale
    ...
)
```

I've tried some examples here, but neither worked on utf8 text (splitted text on á, or ě).

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried this, but it dont keep punctuation and has troubles with some characters (š,ě)
`preg_split('/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

and this:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600649/split-text-into-words-problem-php-complicated-problem`

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [php.net comment](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-split.php#99851) (slightly modified):

```
function mb_str_split( $string ) {
  $split = preg_split('/\b([\(\).,\-\',:!\?;"\{\}\[\]„“»«‘\r\n]*)/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  return array_filter($split, 'filter');
}

function filter($val) {
  if (trim($val) != '') {
    return trim($val);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Test:

```
print_r(mb_str_split("Bára, ta která má hezké oči. To je, ale nepříčetně nehorázné!"));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Bára
    [1] => ,
    [3] => ta
    [5] => která
    [7] => má
    [9] => hezké
    [11] => oči
    [12] => .
    [14] => To
    [16] => je
    [17] => ,
    [19] => ale
    [21] => nepříčetně
    [23] => nehorázné
    [24] => !
)
*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't ! sign be separated?

Comment: Thanks, but i need to split all punctuation:

Comment: Even chars like these:
`"(", ")", ".", "-", "\"", "'", ":", "!", "?", ";", ",", "{", "}", "[", "]", " „", "“", "»", "«", "‚", "‘"," ","\r", "\n"`

Comment: I've updated my answer, with all your signs and inspired by raina77ows awesome use of `\b` :) I hope it works now with all these chars

Comment: Thanks again, but I am afraid that line 3 of your code throws me an error.

Comment: Your PHP version could be too old for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I've edited the code to be compatible with older versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything. (My php version is not that old, its 5.3, that's weird)

Comment: When testing, I've found another problem. When I have sentence:
`Povede se nám rozdělit interpunkci?`
It splits like this:
`[0] => Povede
    [2] => se
    [4] => n
    [5] => á
    [6] => m
    [8] => rozd
    [9] => ě
    [10] => lit
    [12] => interpunkci
    [13] => ?`
instead of
`"Povede","se","nám","rozdělit","interpunkci","?"`

Comment: That's really strange, my result is correct (every word/interpunction splitted). Try to set these above your code: `mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`

Comment: Then I am sorry. I don't know what's wrong; it's working for me

Comment: It was caused by lack of multi-byte support. Colleague of mine wrote this script, which works fine:
`

Comment: what about apostrophes within words like "it's"?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$string   = 'Bára, ta která má hezké oči. To je, ale nepříčetně nehorázné!';
$rawSplit = preg_split('/\b/u', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$result   = array_filter( array_map( function($el) { 
  return trim($el); 
}, $rawSplit));
```