# Need to understand regex posted as an answer to another query

Tags: regex

In this question: [Split text into words problem PHP, complicated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600649)

An answer gave the following regex to split a string into words, being aware of the difference between a decimal point and a full stop.

`/([\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]|\.$|(?<=\D)[:,.\-]|[:,.\-](?=\D))/`

This works for me, but I would like to know WHY it works so that I will eventually be able to write these things on my own. So, my request is:

Please step through that regex and explain what each part does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the original question was that the OP wanted to split around all those special characters but the problem came around when there were numbers in the string with a decimal point like `3.14` and he got bot `3` and `14` in the result, while he only wanted `3.14` itself.

OK to our current problem, let's break your expression into pieces:

```
/([\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]|\.$|(?<=\D)[:,.\-]|[:,.\-](?=\D))/
                             ^   ^              ^
```

As you can see the regex uses an alternation, so it either matches the first piece `[\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]`, the second piece `\.$`, the third piece `(?<=\D)[:,.\-]` or the forth piece `[:,.\-](?=\D))`.

The first piece: `[\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]`

This one matches one of the following characters: a space , `_`, `;`, `?`, `!`, `/`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `<`, `>`, carriage return `\r`, newline `\r` or `"`.

The second piece `\.$`: Matches a dot **only if** it is at the end-of-string.

The third piece: `(?<=\D)[:,.\-]` This matches any of the following characters `:`, `,`, `.`, `-` as long as they are not after a digit `(?<=\D)`, so that things like `3.14` or `23:23` don't cause a split.

The forth and final piece: `[:,.\-](?=\D)` This matches any of the following characters `:`, `,`, `.`, `-` as long as they are followed by a character which is not a digit `(?=\D)`.

This rule is complementary to the third rule.

Comment: What threw me off the most were all the escaped literals,  and I just now got a full understanding of what I've heard called "look behind" (in this case a negative look behind because the "D" is capitalized) and "look ahead". Thank you.

Comment: Note that this pattern doesn't remove the following characters `[:,.-]` if they are at the begining or the end of the string. To solve the problem you must change the lookarounds to `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`. An other thing about character classes, you can short the first to `[][(){}<>\/\s_;?!"]` and you don't need to escape `-` (since it is at the end) in the second and third. The `\.$` alternative will be useless with `[:,.-](?!\d)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you for your feedback. The OP asked for explanation so I didn't think about improving it for him, but your input is welcomed nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

The four alternative parts of this regexp, explained...

```
[\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]
```

Part 1: Appears to be an attempt to match anything that isn't a letter, number or potential *number separator* (of which more in a moment).

```
\.$
```

Part 2: Match a period/full stop at the end of the string.

```
(?<=\D)[:,.\-]|[:,.\-](?=\D)
```

Parts 3/4: Match a *number separator* (colon, comma, period/full stop, minus sign) only if it is immediately preceded or followed by a non-digit character.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add for future reference, if you google [`Explain Regular Expression`](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=) few websites with the tool to parse the expression and break it into pieces with following explanation will show up.

To begin with the starting slash `/` and ending slash `/` are you delimiters.

A delimiter can be any *non-alphanumeric*, *non-backslash*, *non-whitespace character*.

Your regular expression:

```
(                              group and capture to \1:
 [\s_;?!\/\(\)\[\]{}<>\r\n"]   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), 
                               _ ; ? ! \/ \( \) \[ \] { } < > \r \n "
|                              OR
 \.                            '.'
  $                            before an optional \n, and the end of the string
  |                            OR
  (?<=                         look behind to see if there is:
    \D                         non-digits (all but 0-9)
  )                            end of look-behind
  [:,.\-]                      any character of: ':', ',', '.', '\-'
  |                            OR
  [:,.\-]                      any character of: ':', ',', '.', '\-'
  (?=                          look ahead to see if there is:
    \D                         non-digits (all but 0-9)
  )                            end of look-ahead
)                              end of \1
```

Essentially, you have `\r\n` inside your character class and can remove that part since `\s` will match those by itself. And usually only certain characters need escaped inside a character class.

```
(?:[(){}\[\]<>\/!?;_"\s]|\.$|(?<=\D)([;.,-])|(?1)(?=\D))
```

See [`demo`](http://regex101.com/r/vA4jM9)

Hope this helps! Good Luck.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte It's restored.