# PHP Using str_word_count with strsplit to form array after x words

Tags: php, string, strsplit

I've got a large string that I want to put in an array after each 50 words. I thought about using strsplit to cut, but realised that wont take the words in to consideration, just split when it gets to x char.

I've read about str_word_count but can't work out how to put the two together.

What I've got at the moment is:

```
$outputArr = str_split($output, 250);

foreach($outputArr as $arOut){

echo $arOut;
echo "<br />";

}
```

But I want to substitute that to form each item of the array at 50 words instead of 250 characters.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: off-topic: your coming soon page is amazing =)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790596/split-a-text-into-single-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `str_word_count` is sufficient for your needs¹, you can simply call it with `1` as the second parameter and then use `array_chunk` to group the words in groups of 50:

```
$words = str_word_count($string, 1);
$chunks = array_chunk($words, 50);
```

You now have an array of arrays; to join every 50 words together and make it an array of strings you can use

```
foreach ($chunks as &$chunk) { // important: iterate by reference!
    $chunk = implode(' ', $chunk);
}
```

¹ Most probably it is not. If you want to get what most humans consider acceptable results when processing written language you will have to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with some suitable regular expression instead.

Comment: What about words separated by something that is not ` `?

Comment: @raina77ow: You would have to provide an ironclad definition of "word" first. Then, `preg_split`.

Comment: No, that is another question. For example, the previous sentence will be reconstructed as `No that is another question` - if `,` is not considered a part of word `No`, at least.

Comment: @raina77ow: That's because of how `str_word_count` processes text. I explicitly mention that it's unlikely to be sufficient for written language. Regexes are going to be ugly (e.g. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790596/split-a-text-into-single-words), and even that may not be good enough).

Comment: If you want punctuation to be included then you can pass a string of punctuation as a third parameter. E.g. str_word_count($string, 1, ',!?.;:');

Answer (score 0):

There's another way:

```
<?php

$someBigString = <<<SAMPLE
  This, actually, is a nice' old'er string, as they said, "divided and conquered".
SAMPLE;

// change this to whatever you need to:     
$number_of_words = 7; 

$arr = preg_split("#([a-z]+[a-z'-]*(?<!['-]))#i", 
  $someBigString, $number_of_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$res = implode('', array_slice($arr, 0, $number_of_words * 2));
echo $res;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/GuPiSSnS).

I consider `preg_split` a better tool (than `str_word_count`) here. Not because the latter is inflexible (it is not: you can define what symbols can make up a word with its third param), but because `preg_split` will essentially stop processing the string after getting N items.

The trick, as quite common with this function, is to capture delimiters as well, then use them to reconstruct the string with the first N words (where N is given) AND punctuation marks saved.

(of course, the regex used in my example does not strictly comply to `str_word_count` locale-dependent behavior. But it still restricts the words to consist of alpha, `'` and `-` symbols, with the latter two not at the beginning and the end of any word).

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, and what you actually need is splitting the string by 50 words, this solution can be used too - but the main reason to use preg_split will be lost. ) So use Jon's solution instead.