# select 40 words from a string

Tags: php, string

I have a string that can contain up to 2000 chars. I want to only show the first 40 words.

The string is `$row['content']`. How would I only show the first 50?

Thanks.

Comment: Which is it? 40 or 50?

Comment: What does the `mysql` tag have to do with this?

Comment: FYI the top voted answers are returning arrays, to actually output them you will want to pass the result to `implode` to turn them into a string, e.g. `$string = implode(' ',$wordsArray);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming words would be separated by spaces.

```
$words40=explode(" ", $string,41);
unset($words40[40]); // Discard the last element containing the remaining string
```

Of course this will fail on punctuation marks, but since you did not mention whether your string contains something to do with human readable languages or any other value, there is no reason to assume that it will be English Grammar, hence the answer.

**[Reference](http://php.net/explode)**

Comment: This is NOT the way to go. You should at least use a `regexp` to separate in words.

Comment: What difference does that make in this vague scenario?

Comment: FYI this doesn't return the first 40 words. The rest of the string is kept in the last element

Comment: Let's make it 41 and discard the last one

Comment: This is not the best way, punctuation is part of every language. If they are not included in a basic solution then it isn't a solution, put in regex!

Comment: @Edward lol that's funny. Your answer below talks about `array_slice` while you're advocating regex, let's see your regex based answer ill up vote it

Comment: Nah, im no good at regex, thats why i found the simplest way of doing it without using regex but including punctuation (grr), anyway, str_word_count() uses regex behind the scenes ;)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php). But since you want 40/50 **words** and not *signs* you should do something like this:

```
<?php

$string = "Your long string";
$result = preg_split('/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$words = implode(' ', array_slice($result, 0 ,50));

?>
```

Regex from [Split a text into single words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790596/split-a-text-into-single-words)

Answer (score 3):

```
$wordArray = str_word_count($row['content'], 1);
$wordArraySlice = array_slice($wordArray, 0, 40);
$wordString = implode(" ", $wordArraySlice);

echo $wordString;
```

This function counts all the words and returns an array. You can then use array_slice to return the 40 - 50 words you need and then implode them to get a string... if you want.

Comment: Might wanna chuck in an `array_slice` for the final return value

Comment: ahhh. fine. twist my arm!