# Fastest way to search huge list of words stored in file using PHP

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains safe words. I want to be able to check user inputs which arrive as large strings (50-100 words) to make sure that they only contain safe words. I am wondering what is the right approach to do this in PHP.

The only approach I have in mind is looping through user's response word by word and compare against the list of safe words. This approach, unfortunately, leads to memory size issues!

The file that contains the safe words has well over 700K words.

Comment: Make the words the keys of an associative array. Then use `isset($safe_words[$word])`.

Comment: Tempting to suggest in_array, but isset is much, MUCH faster at this

Comment: How can I convert words to keys of an array?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/790602/1301076 but you might need to use array_flip on the result

Comment: PHP is not really built for this type of thing. My experience with large data sets (>10k items) is that it is not acceptable. You should consider another tool and/or change the algorithm.

Comment: What kind of format, line by line words ? Associate array would be fastest.

Comment: Have you tried flipping the logic to validate that it does not contain "un-safe words?"  If this is a moderation-like thing, "safe words" will have to include all of the minor words in the language in question (like, every word I just typed).  Which is a lot of words, particulairly when you only care about those few words like ****, *****, and ******-****-*******.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following code to convert file content in array.
then you can use isset or in_array for further operations.

```
<?php    
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt');       
$arr=array_combine(explode(' ',$homepage));    
$final_arr=array_combine($arr,$arr);    
print_r($final_arr);    
?>
```

hope this can help you.